# Cannot call bundle by jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar

Tags: java, bundler, jruby, jsr223

I've read http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/24/bundler-jruby-complete/ and installed `faraday, rspec and bundler` gems with commands like:

```
export GEM_HOME=/var/lib/tomcat6/shared/gems
export GEM_PATH=/var/lib/tomcat6/shared/gems
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem install bundler
```

And I see these gems in the list provided by

```
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem list
```

I also can require files from these gems in inline jruby script, called through JSR223 from Activiti BPM, which is written in java.

But I failed to run gem binaries, e.g. bundle such way:

```
export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/var/lib/tomcat6/shared/gems
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S bundle
```

**How can I use bundler to manage jruby-complete gems?**

Comment: This is very similar to my question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/31351099/2009612